# ios iphone em protocol is not declared

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this in the `CountryDetailsViewController.h`

```
@class CountryDetailsViewController;
@protocol CountryDetailsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) didCancel: (CountryDetailsViewController *) controller;
-(void) didDone: (CountryDetailsViewController *) controller;

@end

@interface CountryDetailsViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CountryDetailsViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(IBAction)didCancel:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)didDone:(id)sender;
@end
```

and in the `CountriesViewController` i have this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CountryDetailsViewController.h"

@interface CountriesViewController : UITableViewController<em><CountryDetailsViewControllerDelegate></em>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * _countires;

@end
```

#### The xcode gives me this error:

[image]

Comment: Like `JamesFrost` has said stop copying and pasting from websites -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the HTML markup:

```
@interface CountriesViewController : UITableViewController <CountryDetailsViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: And in the future, don't copy and paste code directly from websites without understanding what it does.

Comment: @JamesFrost I am sorry for doing that

Comment: why your answer takes positive votes while my question takes negative votes ?